# What's the equivalent of PostMessage to self, for Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, controls

I'm writing a custom control derived from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.

The control is using the `Control.KeyDown` event, to watch keystrokes: I should handle some keystrokes (for example `<Ctrl>-K`) as hotkeys, which cause me to launch a dialog box.

If I launch the dialog from my `onKeyDown` event handler, the dialog is displayed before I set `KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress` to `true` and return (and so I'm failing to suppress the `K` keypress). Instead, I'd like to return from the `onKeyDown` event handler, and launch the dialog afterwards. To do this, after I return from the `onKeyDown` event handler I need to be invoked again somehow, with some kind of 'launch the dialog' event.

On Win32, I could generate this event by using the `PostMessage` API, to send a registered window message to myself: I would receive this message right after any previous message in my message queue, and use it as the signal to launch my dialog. Here however I can't use `PostMessage` function (nor the `WndProc` method) because I want to use strictly **managed** APIs (without needing `SecurityPermissionFlag::UnmanagedCode`).

So what would be the managed equivalent, for a thread (my UI thread) to schedule an asynchronous callback: perhaps a timer of some kind? Some kind of self-`Invoke`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought was "set the SurpressKeyPress property *before* opening the dialog", but that's not really answering your question.  If you really need to return from the event handler before opening the dialog, take a look at the BeginInvoke method.

you could do something like this:

```
...
this.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(showDlg));
KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress = true;
...


public void showDlg()
{
   // create and show dialog here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had wrongly assumed that a Control's calling BeginInvoke on itself would result in a synchrnous call.

Comment: @JimHarte Here InvokeDelegate is a delegate in the .NET framework or is it one I need to declare myself?

Comment: @AgnelKurian your own. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can kick off the dialog from a method defined in your form, and start the method from a new thread (include System.Threading in your using statements).  The code in your button click event will look something like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LaunchDialog));
thread.Start();
```

where LaunchDialog is the method that launches the new dialog window.

Comment: I want the dialog to be modal: which disables its parent window, and gets all keystrokes until it's dismissed. I'm nervous about having multiple threads drive the windows of a single UI. I usually have onne UI thread, with any worker threads not touching the UI. Do you think your suggestion is safe?

Comment: No, my suggestion is not a good idea. I never use threads unless I have to, and it's extremely rare that I have to. I don't really understand why you can't just launch the modal dialog from the click event, have the user interact with it, and then close the dialog.

Comment: Maybe remove this answer if we're not happy with it?

Comment: If I launch it from the KeyDown event (before I set KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress to true and return) then, while the dialog is displayed, the control receives the subsequent KeyPress event (which wasn't suppressed).

Comment: @Aardvark: that's not how SO works. Sometimes, even a wrong or not-ideal answer is useful to other people for other purposes.